# How can I visualize Android call stack using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, callstack, ddms

Is there anyway I could visualize the call stack of an Android app? All I can find in Eclipse are the running threads:

[image]

What I want, is to see how my subroutines are called in order to debug an issue related to the activities back stack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add break points in your code somewhere and run in debug mode, you may see call stack then. AFAIK, While run mode it just displays number of threads and process. It doesn't display sequence of calls.

Answer (score 6):

You can see the *instantaneous* call stack in any of your threads. In the DDMS perspective of Eclipse, click on the Threads window.

[image]

It'll be empty to start. Select your process on the Devices window, then click on the threads button above the list of processes in the Devices list.

[image]

Now you'll see a list of threads in the Threads window. Click on one of the threads and then press the Refresh button below. You'll see the instantaneous stack trace of that thread.

[image]