# Debug the Android back stack in eclipse

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Is there a way to visualize the backstack with activities and fragements in Android in the Eclipse ADT IDE?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295971/how-can-i-visualize-android-call-stack-using-eclipse) post.

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean just see what it looks like for debugging purposes? In that case, define

```
public static void displayBackStack(FragmentManager fm) {
    int count = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
    Log.d("Backstack log", "There are " + count + " entries");
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        // Display Backstack-entry data like
        String name = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName();
        Log.d("Backstack log", "entry " + i + ": " + name);
    }
}
```

in some class `C` and call

```
C.displayBackStack(getFragmentManager());
```

or

```
C.displayBackStack(getSupportFragmentManager()); // with compatibility package
```

from your activity. This puts the BackStack in your log.

Of course, you can vary the data that you display according to your needs.

Comment: I meant rather to use a gui tool in eclipse ADT like the layout hierarchy viewer. But logging out some debug messages  should be enough.

Comment: Note that this only handles fragments. I am not aware of any way to get at the back stack at the activity level, in large part because they might not be your activities, but rather ones from other apps.

Comment: A tool to display all fragments and activities in the backstack will be some cool thing.

Comment: note that you need to supply a name when adding to the backStack. for example: addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())