# popBackStack() seems to have no effect

Tags: android, android-fragments

Using the `displayBackStack()` method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235489/debug-the-android-back-stack-in-eclipse/11235642?noredirect=1#comment31342472_11235642)

I have the code below in my app (for debugging). `displayBackStack()` is called 3 times: to show initial state, after `popBackStack()`, after `addBackStack()`. The initial state of the stack has 2 entries. After the `popBackStack()`, I would expect to see 1 entry, but I still see the same 2, so my expectations must be incorrect. What is the problem?

UPDATE:
On Gavi's suggestion, stack can be seen to have just 1 entry after pop. The problem then becomes that the state of the stack after the `addBackStack()` call is now just 1 entry. There doesn't seem to be an `addBackStackImmediate()` to use here

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
Utilities.displayBackStack(fragmentManager); // initial state

Game1Fragment fragment = new Game1Fragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentManager.popBackStack(); 
fragmentTransaction.commit();
// use these 2 statements instead to see the pop (@Gavi)
//fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(); 
//fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); 
Utilities.displayBackStack(fragmentManager); // after pop

fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(mainFragmentContainerLayout.getId(), fragment, tag); // so that back key goes back to menu, not exit the app
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack"(Game1Fragment"); // so that back key goes back to menu, not exit the app
Utilities.displayBackStack(fragmentManager);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `commitAllowingStateLoss()`

and

```
popBackStackImmediate()
```

Comment: So these statements do allow me to see the changes to the stack 'in real time' so to speak. Afa I can see, I need this only for debugging, Is there any reason to do this otherwise?

Comment: That's not entirely correct - the methods I mentioned differ from "your" methods in the priority the system gives them (their execution). You can read the docs for the specific cases nd priorities...